# Compute the mean of a Tensorflow Tensor keeping its shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.7.7 and Tensorflow 2.1.0.

I have this tensor:

```
tf.Tensor([...], shape=(5, 512), dtype=float32)
```

And I want to compute its mean on each of its elements, getting a tensor with shape `(1, 512)` but I don't know how. I have tried `tf.math.reduce_mean` but it returns a number.

This is what I have tried:

```
support_set_embeddings = encoder(X_train) # tf.Tensor([...], shape=(5, 512), dtype=float32)
class_prototype = tf.math.reduce_mean(support_set_embeddings, axis=1) # tf.Tensor([...], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

If I change the axis in `reduce_mean` I get a tensor with shape `(512,)`:

```
support_set_embeddings = encoder(X_train) # tf.Tensor([...], shape=(5, 512), dtype=float32)
class_prototype = tf.math.reduce_mean(support_set_embeddings, axis=0) # tf.Tensor([...], shape=(512,), dtype=float32)
```

How can I compute the mean of each elements of a Tensor like I have explained above?

I'm looking for a tensor with shape `(1,512)`.

Comment: Did you try changing dimensions of your (512,) shaped tensor? Is it not what you need?

Comment: Doing a `tf.expand_dims(class_prototype,axis=0)` gives you a tensor of shape (1,512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reshape..
`tf.reshape(tf.reduce_mean(your_tensor, axis=0), (1,512))`